# Global variables always detrimental to Julia's performance?

Tags: performance, scope, julia, global-variables

Every corner of Julia's documentation is filled with reminders to "avoid global scope variables". But I fail to see how this could be beneficial even in some of the most common data analysis scenarios, probably due to a misunderstanding regarding how Julia's compiler works.

For example, one function I use checks whether each token of a document belongs to a *huge* lexicon of acceptable tokens. Currently, I use something like this:

```
using CSV, DataFrames

accepted_tokens = @chain begin
    CSV.read("accepted_tokens.csv", DataFrame)
    Set{String}(_.tokens)
end

function redact_document(doc::String)
    tokens = split(doc, " ")
    redacted_tokens = [token in accepted_tokens ? token : "REDACTED" for token in tokens]
    return join(" ", redacted_tokens)
end
```

Now, since `redact_document` is the only function the uses `accepted_tokens` I of course could just assign the variable inside the function, like this:

```
function redact_document(doc::String)
    accepted_tokens = @chain begin
        CSV.read("accepted_tokens.csv", DataFrame)
        Set{String}(_.tokens)
    end

    tokens = split(doc, " ")
    redacted_tokens = [token in accepted_tokens ? token : "REDACTED" for token in tokens]
    return join(" ", redacted_tokens)
end
```

The reason I don't do this is that it seems to me that in this case `accedted_tokens` would need to be assigned *each* time `redact_document` is called, which seems like a total waste of time, given that I'd have to read a huge file from disk every time, instead of creating/assigning the variable just once (albeit in the global scope). I also don't want to declare `accepted_tokens` as a constant, since I might want to tweak the lexicon as I develop my script.

Am I right on my reading of the code? Or, as I suspect, the compiler is smarter than what I take it to be, and I should still be wrapping my variables within the functions that use them?

Comment: Why you dont simply pass `accepted_tokens` as second parameter to the `redact_document` function ? They would not be copied

Comment: I think you have a dire misunderstanding. Why don't you use a `const`ant variable in the global scope instead of this nasty approach?

Comment: @Shayan:  As per the OP: "I don't want to declare `accepted_tokens` as a constant, since I might want to tweak the lexicon as I develop my script".
@Antonello: Wouldn't that approach still need to read `CSV` every time the function is called?

Comment: The correct answer is to do what @Antonello suggests: pass `accepted_tokens` as an input argument. In fact, that should be written as an answer.

Comment: @DNF: But even if I pass  `accepted_tokens` as a parameter, won't I still need to assign it in the global scope?

Comment: @DNF, How is that going to prevent defining a global scope variable?

Comment: @Dijkie85: You can define it in a global scope or in some other scope outside `redact_document`. The point is that inside `redact_document` it will be a local variable.

Comment: @Shayan: I don't understand your question.

Comment: If the variable is passed as argument, the Julia compiler will specialize the function to assume type stability inside the [token..] statement list comprehension. Otherwise the code is potentially type unstable and usually slower in the comprehension's loop if `tokens` is a large array.

Comment: @DNF, My question is the same as *Dijkie85* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74199350/global-variables-always-detrimental-to-julias-performance?noredirect=1#comment131005404_74199350).

Comment: @DNF: But what I'm trying to do is avoiding using the global scope at all. I understand I can pass any variable as a function parameter instead of referring to the global scope from inside the function, but am I not supposed to NOT define variables in the global scope to begin with?

Comment: No, one uses the global scope all the time for interactive work. If you have an application, you probably have a `main` function where everything happens, but for REPL work globals are common. But avoid having your functions access globals (at least non-const), pass them as arguments instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While all has been said in comments, just for cleanness your code should look like this (you should pass `accepted_tokens` as argument rather than to use a global variable):

```
function redact_document(doc::AbstractString, accepted_tokens::AbstractSet{<:AbstractString})
    tokens = split(doc, " ")
    redacted_tokens = [token in accepted_tokens ? token : "REDACTED" for token in tokens]
    return join(" ", redacted_tokens)
end
```

The type declarations for function arguments are optional (do not affect performance), but if you use the usually it is better to use their abstract counterparts.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `join(redacted_tokens, " ")`? The reverse order gives me an empty string.